# Is my class threadsafe? If not why?

Tags: java

Is my class threadsafe? If not why?

```
class Foo {
 boolean b = false;

 void doSomething() throws Exception {
    while (b) Thread.sleep();
 }

 void setB(boolean b) {
     this.b = b;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code is not thread safe because a running thread may see changes until the code is compiled (which could be at a random point later) and you no longer see changes.

BTW: This makes testing it very hard to do. e.g. if you sleep for 1 second you might not see this behaviour for almost three hours.

i.e. it may or may not work and you cannot say just because it has worked it will continue to work.

---

As `b` is not `volatile` the JIT can and will optimise

```
while (b) Thread.sleep(N);
```

to be

```
boolean b = this.b;
if (b) while (true) Thread.sleep(N);
```

so the value of `b` is not read each time.

Comment: @Nambari The connection is perhaps obscure so I have tried to clarify it.

Answer (score 7):

It is not. `setB()` updating instance variable `b` value but is not `synchronized`.

Multiple threads may try to execute `setB()` method at same point of time may result in un-predicted results.

You need to `synchronize` the method (or) use `synchronize` block with lock on `this` object.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [AtomicBoolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html). This will mean that only one thread can access it at any one time.

Comment: +1 So will making the field `volatile` (which is what AtomicBoolean does) AtomicBoolean is useful if you want to do more than just set or get.

Answer (score 3):

> But, how is it relates to thread safety? little confused.

It goes back to the definition of "thread-safe".  Wikipedia says this:

> *"Thread safety is a computer programming concept applicable in the context of multi-threaded programs. A piece of code is thread-safe if it functions correctly during simultaneous execution by multiple threads."*

The key point here is *functions correctly*.  If you look at the scenario explained by Peter Lawrey, you can see that JIT compilation can result in code that doesn't notice when the value of `b` changes from `true` to `false`, and instead loops for ever.  This is clearly incorrect behaviour.  And since this only manifests when there are two threads, it is a thread-safety issue.

Answer (score 0):

An at-issue concept here is visibility, discussed in Concurrent Java.  If doSomething() is running on a different thread, the JVM makes no guarantee that the action taken in setB will apply to the version of b that doSomething sees.  So you could call setB and doSomething is not guaranteed to ever terminate.